# PHP ORM that does not polute Business Objects

Tags: php, orm

I have inherited a medium sized project that I would like to add an ORM to.  I have checked out all the normal options Doctrine, Propel redbean , but they all seem to require me to pollute the business objects with their specific implementations.  What I would really like (not sure if it is possible) is to pass my business object with its getters and setters etc and have the ORM persist  the values.   My main concern here is not tying the app to the ORM.

Comment: `not tying the app to the ORM` -- programmers solve **real** problems, philosophers find the abstract tool for abstract issue. What I wanted to say is that writing abstract code that can be used for any ORM makes no sense in real life. You either use some tool with all its pros and cons or look for pixie dust for years.

Comment: :-) Yeah @zerkms , I know what your saying, I guess some of the problem is me not having the confidence to just bite the bullet with a particular ORM.

Comment: just to explain what I meant (the intention wasn't to be rude, no) - the specific solutions are always better than abstract, just because in such case you could use all the power of a particular tool. This makes able to write efficient and handy code. So I would choose Doctrine2 if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm). It doesn't implement [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) (which, I think, you consider as a "pollution"), but instead a [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern. You can configure Doctrine using [annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html).

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class Post
{
    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") **/
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $title;
    /** @Column(type="text") **/
    protected $body;
}
```

And then

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$loader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader("Doctrine");
$loader->register();

$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'tests'
);
$path = 'path/to/entities';
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($path, true);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
..................
$entityManager->persist($post);
```

Comment: Thanks @FractalizeR of all the ones I looked at Doctrine does seem have the best abstraction.  The only thing that I thought was polluting about it was the use of special "Doctrine" ArrayCollection types for related models that are included in the object class. In the examples anyway.